# Sublime Regex - First instance and move to next line

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I've got a list of categories here at the moment that are formatted like so:

```
["Handmade"]["Other"]["Clothing"],
["Handmade"]["Other"]["Accessories"],
["Handmade"]["Other"]["Woodwork"],
["Handmade"]["Other"]["Other"]
```

I need to replace the first "][" in Sublime. I can select them using this:

```
\]\[
```

But it will select all of them and not the first instance. Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? You could 1) select all, 2) split selection into lines, 3) edit many lines at one time.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace the first `][` pair in each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to replace the first `][` pair in each line with other characters. For example, you want to replace the first `][` pair with `//`.

## How to do

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the find the replace panel. In the `Find` field, use the regular expression: `(^\["\w+")\]\[`. In the `Replace` field, use `$1//`.
See the following image for clearer configurations.

[image]

The above setting will correctly replace the first `][` pair in each line with `//`.

## Explanation

The expression `^\["\w+"` will match all characters before the first `][` pair. We enclose this regular expression to [form a group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) for later reference.

In the `Replace` field, we can use `$1` or `\1` to refer to the group to avoid repetition.

A useful cheat sheet for regular expression in sublime text is [this one](https://github.com/dmikalova/sublime-cheat-sheets/blob/master/cheat-sheets/Regular%20Expressions.cheatsheet).

Comment: Awesome, absolutely fantastic. I've had to format this mainly with flat file to due the fact all these 500 fields aren't in a database. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. You can edit your post to make it clearer. A clearer question will be answered more quickly.  :)